# Is there any common acoustic feature between adults and children(aged between 10-16)

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, feature-selection, speech

In order to use the data-set from two groups(adults and children). Is there any common acoustic feature(s) between the two groups

Comment: As part of writing a question on Stack Overflow, you're supposed to explain what you've tried already. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I tried MFCC features but it didn't work